# trying to write a piecewise function

Tags: equations, errors

I am trying to write a piecewise function using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
$ e^x x\in [-1,1] $
\\
$[x]  x\notin [-1,1] $
\end{cases}
\end{document}
```

The result I am looking for should look like this
[image]

But instead I get the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 $
      e^x  x\in [-1,1] $
?
```

I tried using \usepackage{amsmath}. But that generates a different error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@mathaccent ...2}\hexnumber@ #1#4}\MakeRobust 
                                                  #2
l.770 \@tempa{\hat}

?
```

Can someone please correct this or tell me any alternate way to generate the function.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 e^x & x\in [-1,1] \\{}
[x] & x\not\in [-1,1] 
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be in math mode to use the `cases` environment. Use this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
.................

\[
f(x)= \begin{cases}
 e^x, & x\in [-1,1], \\
[x], &  x\notin [-1,1].
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: it generates the following error " ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.6  e^x, &
            x\in [-1,1], \\
? "  Did it compile without error for you

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash This is because Bernard does not tell you that you need to load `amsmath`. Use [my comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schrödingers-cat).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat using amsmath genertes the error "! Undefined control sequence.
\set@mathaccent ...2}\hexnumber@ #1#4}\MakeRobust 
                                                  #2
l.770 \@tempa{\hat}

? " Is there any way of doing it without amsmath

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I did think the O.P. was already loading amsmath since he used `cases`, and I focused on the syntax  error.

Comment: @Bernard The OP's MWE is complete and unambiguous, it does not load `amsmath`.

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash: You have the error message just adding `amsmath` to *this* code?

Comment: @Bernard yes every time i use amsmath it creates the same error

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash Then you load something else in addition. You do not need to load `amsmath`, you can do it with a simple array. Of course, this more or less reinvents what `amsmath` does.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Can you show me how?

Comment: Could please post a minimal, yet compilable, code reproducing this problem?

Comment: @Bernard You mean another code with amsmath which generates the same error

Comment: I just mean a (short) real code with amsmath that generates the same error for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution without `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{@{\mathstrut}l@{\quad}l}
 e^x & x\in [-1,1] \\[1ex]
[x] & x\not\in [-1,1] 
\end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course I myself would not want to use packages that prevent me from using `amsmath`, but you may have very good reasons.

Comment: error"! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 4.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> untitled-3.tex
                  
? " Did this code compile for you

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash No, it doesn't. If that happens when you compile this very file, there must be something wrong with your TeX installation.

Comment: can you suggest where i can get a better one

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash There are two major TeX installations: TeXLive and MikTeX. I am using a Mac and have installed MacTeX, which utilizes the TeXLive installation.