# Why can't I write a piecewise function successfully in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
 S(t) & =
\begin{cases}
C_0 + N_0(x_0)\cdot B \cdot a_{x_0}\cdot (1 + l_P) & t= 0\\
\hat{S}(t) - B \cdot N_0(x_0+t)  & t= 1,2,\cdots
\end{cases}.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

There exists a error and the output is
[image]

I want the output like this:

[image]

Comment: You're missing `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: @ Henri  Yes,it can successfully run.However,if I don't use \usepackage{amsmath} ,how can i make it?

Comment: @Henri I find the answer here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529689/trying-to-write-a-piecewise-function   However,is not work for me ,are there must be something wrong with my TeX installation?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without `amsmath`?  It's one of the core standard packages that should always be available and it is practically mandatory for any serious math typesetting.

Comment: Without `amsmath` you can do it with `array`: http://dpaste.com/32Y5K7E (expires in 10 days)

Comment: @Henri  Because when I use amsmath, it will change the format of my thesis and produce many errors and warnings. I just learn Latex for two days, and don't know why it will happen.

Comment: Then you should invest some time into properly learning LaTeX and definitely invest time into switching to `amsmath` and fixing those errors.  It will save you so much time in the long run.

Comment: @Henri Yes,sure,thank you very much for your suggestions. I will try to fix those errors and warnings. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `amsmath` package or do it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[S(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
                C_0 + N_0(x_0)\cdot B \cdot a_{x_0}\cdot (1 + l_P) & t= 0\\
                \hat{S}(t) - B \cdot N_0(x_0+t)  & t= 1,2,\cdots
              \end{array}\right.\]
\end{document}
```

This second option will give you this:

[image]

Comment: probably an idea to use `{@{} ll }` as that is what the `cases` env does (or something similar)